# How to get a certain column in SQLserver to combo box?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, foreign-keys

Here is my big dilemma in programming in VB.
I want to make an 'Admission' form and display a certain context?? in the DataGridView with a foreign key.

I've made a table

```
CREATE TABLE Admission
    (
     AdmissionID NUMERIC IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_Admission PRIMARY KEY
    ,paID NUMERIC FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES pInformation ( paId )
    ,DateAdmit DATE NOT NULL
    ,doctorID NUMERIC FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Doctor ( doctorid )
    ,roomId VARCHAR(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES room ( roomid )
    ,Status VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
    ,Remarks VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
    ,DateDischarged DATE NOT NULL
    )
```

And I want to display that in DataGridview. So I've done it. I've made a 3 combo box for the three foreign keys, so that the combo box will display inserted data in the table. Like this, I have a table with a `paID` primary key. I want that the user will see all the `paID` in the `combobox1`.

Comment: Show the code you're having an issue with and explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: When I try to add data source it and run it. The combo box displays "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: No sir. I don't have a code issue in here. I just don't know how to display the paID properly in the combobox

Answer (score 0):

_I dont know what version of visual studio you are using but at least in earlier versions there was properties like Data Source And Display member in combobox. With display member you could select which column form Data Source table is shown in combobox.

Comment: Yes, that is what im doing. But whenever i run VS2010. The combobox just display "System.Data.DataRowView"